# Doxygen not generating documentation for interface with generic and non generic variants

Tags: c#, doxygen

I have a non generic interface (simplified for illustration): -

```
   public interface IResource
   {
      string Title { get; }
      object CreateInstance();
   }
```

I then have a generic variant of this: -

```
   public interface IResource<T> : IResource
   {
      new T CreateInstance();
   }
```

Doxygen generates docs for the non generic IResource but it is empty (none of the methods and properties appear) and the generic variant has no docs at all.

How can get the method documentation to appear?

Comment: You mentioned this problem in 2014, unfortunately without doxygen version number (1.8.7 ?), please have a try with the current version (1.8.12)